# TouchAction deprecated in Selenium 4

Tags: mobile, automation, appium, appium-ios, selenium4

Here is my code to bring the Keyboard on the real ipad devices. Since Touch actions is been deprecated in Selenium 4. Can anyone help with the new solution?

```
public void tapOnElementToBringKeyboard(By locator) {
TeasyElement element = element(locator);
clickActions(locator);
int fromX = element.getLocation().getX();
int fromY = element.getLocation().getY();

TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction((IOSDriver<?>) getDriver());
touchAction.tap(PointOption.point(fromX, fromY)).release().perform().tap(PointOption.point(fromX, fromY)) .release().perform();
}
```

```
Dont have any solution
```

Comment: Allready answered for Python in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74854594/20443541